# Can I create a Model in MapInfo, like in ArcGIS? (Modelbuilder)

Tags: modelbuilder, mapinfo

I have some Forumlas I use quiet often. I want to create a Model like in ArcGIS with it(Drag&Drop put in some Parameters, and so forth), is that possible?

Is there a GUI for that? Or is it only possible to write MapBasic code?

Comment: MapBasic is the only real option for customization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that is one of many things missing in the Mapinfo. The only way to automatize tasks like that is - you get it right - learn Mapbasic and create your own tool. If you can install other software and spent a lot of money - as mentioned before there is server solution called Spectrum. But there is also other - freeware/open source software way. GDAL supports Mapinfo formats (both mif and tab) plus many other vector, grid and image formats. And **QGIS uses GDAL and have now graphical modeller** under processing menu - [more about graphicall modeller](https://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html). Of course it all depends what you want to achieve with your model.

Answer (score 4):

No - is the most accurate answer. **[MapBasic](http://www.pbinsight.com.au/support/product-documentation/details/mapinfo-mapbasic)** is a scripting language and has no out of the box GUI.

**[Spectrum](http://www.pitneybowes.com.au/software/data-management/data-quality/Spectrum-Universal-Addressing-Module.shtml)** does, but to be honest, I think thats squashing a fly with a sledgehammer. You would be looking at multiples of tens of thousands of dollars for that solution.

Have you looked at **[Safe Software's FME](http://www.safe.com/)**? Personally based on reading between the lines of your question that would be the most appropriate tool for the job.

Comment: +1 for FME. We use FME and MapInfo very heavily and FME supports all the MapInfo specific components, such as styling and bounds. It's totally worth the money.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a dekstop option, MapBasic it is.

If  you are looking for a server solution have a closer look at Spectrum (Spatial).